# getting length of utf8mb4 string with perl from MySql

Tags: mysql, string, perl, utf8mb4

i wrote a small perl function that takes a string and checks its length without the spaces. the basic code looks as follows:

```
sub foo
{
   use utf8;
   my @wordsArray = split(/ /, $_[0]));
   my $result = length(join('', @wordsArray));
   return $result;
}
```

When i provide this function with a string containing special characters (such as hebrew letters), it seems to work great.
the problem starts when i use a value coming from MySql column, with a character set of utf8mb4: in such case, the value being calculated is higher than the value in the previous example.

I can guess why such behavior occurs: the special characters are written in a 4 byte manner in the table, and thus each letter calculates as two characters in the utf8 encoding.

Does anyone know how the above can be resolved, so that i will get the right number of characters from a string coming from DB table defined as utf8mb4?

**EDIT:**

Some more information regarding the above code:

The DB column used as an argument for the function is of type VARCHAR(1000), with collation of utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
I am fetching the row via a MySql connection configured as follows:

```
$mySql = DBI->connect(
  "DBI:mysql:$db_info{'database'}:$db_info{'hostname'};mysql_multi_statements=1;",
  "$db_info{'user'}",
  "$db_info{'password'}",
  {'RaiseError' => 1,'AutoCommit' => 0});
...
$mySql->do("set names utf8mb4");
```

an example data value would be "שלום עולם" (which in hebrew means "Hello World").

1) When calling `foo($request->{VALUE});` (where VALUE is the column data from DB), the result is 16 (where each hebrew character is counted as two characters, and one space between them is disregarded). Dumper in this case is:

```
$VAR1 = "\327\251\327\234\327\225\327\235 \327\242\327\225\327\234\327\235";
```

2) When calling `foo("שלום עולם");`:

- when declaring `use utf8;`, the result is 8 (as there are 8 visible characters in this string). Dumper (Useqq=1) in this case is:

  $VAR1 = "\x{5e9}\x{5dc}\x{5d5}\x{5dd} \x{5e2}\x{5d5}\x{5dc}\x{5dd}";
- when not declaring `use utf8;', the result is 16, and is similar to the case of sending the value from DB:

  $VAR1 = "\327\251\327\234\327\225\327\235 \327\242\327\225\327\234\327\235";

Looks like i need to find a way of converting the received value to UTF8 before starting to work with it.

Comment: That's better written as `sub foo { $_[0] =~ tr/ //c; }`

Comment: thanks, but that's not really helping me now, is it? :)

Comment: Which is why it's a comment and not a solution

Comment: Smart-ass comments like that will only reduce your chances of getting any useful help. No one here is getting paid to write a solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What MySQL calls `utf8` is a limited subset of UTF-8 which allows only three bytes per character and covers code points up to 0xFFFF. Even `utf8mb4` doesn't cover the full UTF-8 range, which supports encoded characters up to 6 bytes long

The consequence is that any data from either a `utf8` or a `utf8mb4` column is simply a UTF-8 string in Perl and there should be no difference between the two database encodings

It is my guess that you haven't enabled UTF-8 for your `DBI` handle, so everything is being treated as just a sequence of bytes. You should enable the `mysql_enable_utf8` when you make the `connect` call, which should then look something like

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 });
```

---

With the additional data, I can see that the string you are retrieving from the database is indeed שלום עולם UTF-8-encoded

However, if I decode it, then first of all I get a non-space character count of 8 from both your `foo` subroutine and my own, not 9; and also you should be getting *characters* back from the database, not bytes

I suspect that you may have written an encoded string to the database in the first place. Here's a short program that creates a MySQL table, writes two records to it (one character string and one encoded string) and retrieves what it has written. You will see that The only thing that makes a difference is the setting of `mysql_enable_utf8`. The behaviour is the same whether or not the original string is encoded, and with or without `SET NAMES utf8mb4`

Further experimentation showed that *either* `mysql_enable_utf8` *or* `SET NAMES utf8mb4` will get DBI to *write* the data correctly, but the latter has no effect on *reading*

***I suggest that your solution should be to use ONLY `mysql_enable_utf8` when either reading or writing***

You should also `use utf8` only at the top of all your programs. Missing this out means you can't use any non-ASCII characters in your code

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $VAR1 = "\327\251\327\234\327\225\327\235 \327\242\327\225\327\234\327\235";

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    qw/ DBI:mysql:database=temp admin admin /, {
        RaiseError => 1,
        PrintError => 0,
        mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
    }
) or die DBI::errstr;

$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8mb4');

$dbh->do('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp');
$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE temp (value VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4)');

my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO temp (value) VALUES (?)');
$insert->execute('שלום עולם');
$insert->execute($VAR1);

my $values = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref('SELECT value FROM temp');
printf "string: %s  foo: %d\n", $_, foo($_) for @$values;

sub foo2 {
  $_[0] =~ tr/ //c;
}

sub foo {
  length join '', split / /, $_[0];
}
```

**output with `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1`**

```
string: שלום עולם  foo: 8
string: שלום עולם  foo: 8
```

**output with `mysql_enable_utf8 => 0`**

```
string: ×©××× ×¢×××  foo: 16
string: ×©××× ×¢×××  foo: 16
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Borodin!
though my connection code does not enable utf8 as you suggested, it is running the following after connection has been established:

$mySql->do( "set names utf8mb4" );

i'm sure i added that part of code after running into some issues in the past.

would enabling utf8 collide with the "set names" i added?

Comment: @chikko: All `use utf8` does is tell the compiler that the source code of the program is in UTF-8. It should really be right at the top of the file and won't have any effect at all within that subroutine

Comment: Ah you mean the `mysql_enable_utf8` option. I'm not sure, and the documentation isn't clear about that. I would try enabling the option and removing the `set names` to see if that works

Comment: yes, only later did i realize that.
(my code obviously does something more than what i stated above - this was just an example).

i'll try adding the mysql_enable_utf8 attribute to the connection string and update. thanks again

Comment: i tried adding the mysql_enable_utf8 attribute with and without removing the set names part - unfortunately both of them yeilded the same result as before. these special characters must have a different representation in utf8mb4... btw - in php, for example, they have special treatment for counting such encoding's characters: the mb_strlen function.

Comment: @chikko: `mb_strlen` is simply a length function that allows you to specify an encoding parameter as well. In theory, once you have it set up properly, the string you fetch from the database should already be decoded. I suggest you use `Data::Dump` (or `Data::Dumper` with `$Data::Dumper::Useqq` set to 1) to view what you're actually getting back. I might set up a test MySQL database if I have a moment. Can you give me some idea of your data?

Comment: There has not been any 5- or 6-byte sequences since 2003

Comment: @Borodin: looks like changing the value from DB with decode('utf-8', $_[0]); right at the beginning fies everything for me, as the value from DB returned without the UTF8 encoding.
Even though i did not use your latest reply, your help and support have led me to resolution - thank you very much for that! i'm marking your reply as my answer.

Comment: @Chikko: No, you shouldn't do that. Your database request should return the *decoded string*, and decoding it manually is a hack to make up for previous bug in your code. I would have suggested that long ago if it was the right solution

Comment: @Borodin: Production environment is currently working as intended - but of course you are right - this solution is just a workaround. i will create a test code which will contain the mysql_enable_utf8 flag, and update production as soon as i can.

thanks again :)